# weird url pattern through a form submission in django

Tags: django, forms, django-urls

I have a form on a page:

```
    <form id="create_event" method="post" action="{% url app.views.create_event course.id %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ eventForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="add event">
    </form>
```

And in my urls.py I have

```
(r'^item/(?P<item_id>\w+)/create_event/$', create_event),
(r'^item/(?P<item_id>\w+)/$', item),
```

I have both the functions create_event and item working on my localhost.

However, for some reason when I press submit on the form my server side (1.2.3 on webfaction, I'm stuck with using 1.2.3) django throws the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://my_url/item/1/create_event/app.views.course
```

When I replaced the {% url app.views.create_event course_id %} with a hard coded URL it still somehow appended the method name to the URL. Could this be a problem with 1.2.3 not yet having some of the functionality I'm used to using from 1.3?

Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't possible for django to change your hard coded URL into the view method's name, so I'm guessing your django process on your server didn't get restarted and therefore isn't reflecting your code change.

Comment: @dgel I did restart the server a couple of times, I had also double checked in the rendered source html that that the url was the right url (both before and after hard coding the url).

Comment: I still maintain it isn't possible for django to replace a hard coded URL with a view name. Try hard coding the URL to some arbitrary text (that doesn't correspond to a view) to make absolutely certain that your changes are being applied.

Comment: Yep, changing it to "/hello/" and resetting the server makes it go and search for /hello/ in the dispatcher (which it doesn't find).

And, that made me just double checked my DB and it looks like the items are being added, so I guess it is processing the form - the problem is obviously somewhere else. Pretty bad testing on my part :/

Comment: Perhaps it's a bad redirect in `create_event`?

Comment: Yeah, looks like most likely, I'm using:

    return redirect('app.views.item', item_id = item_id)

It is the first time I'm using redirect, so could be that I'm doing it wrong. I guess it looks like it's redirecting to the current page and then trying to add 'app.views.item' to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your urls to:

```
(r'^item/(?P<item_id>\w+)/$', item, name='item'),
```

Then change your redirect in `create_event` to:

```
return redirect('item', item_id = item_id)
```

Comment: Worked! I had to add url to the beginning of the pattern (so url(r^...) ), but yep, I think I will in the future. Thanks for all the help!